# gnuplot set equal distance for ticks on both axes

Tags: gnuplot

In gnuplot, I want to plot with x-ticks as [0,1,2,...] and y-ticks as [0,2,4,...], but I also want the tick on both axes to have the same length to make the plot look nicer. I tried

```
set size ratio 1
set xtics 0,1,6
set ytics 0,2,10
```

But that does not work. How could I do that?

An example plot is below
[image]
(source: Computational Plasticity, de Souza Neto)

Comment: Could you please add an illustration? What do you mean with "same tick length"? The length of the tick bar itself or the same visual appearance of the _distance_ between 0,1,2 in x and 0,2,4 in y? What gnuplot version and which terminal are you using?

Comment: Thanks for adding an example. So, you want that the rectangle from (0,0) to (1,2) looks like a square?

Comment: @theozh That's right. I thought setting the same ratio will do but it doesn't :((((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you have 5 units in y-direction and 6 units in x-direction. In order to give them the same visual length you need to set:

```
set size ratio 5./6.   # decimal point to avoid gnuplot's integer division
```

Check `help size`.

**Script:**

```
### set aspect ratio
reset session

set size ratio 5./6.

set xrange[0:6]
set xtics 1
set yrange[0:10]
set ytics 2
set grid x,y

plot x**2
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]